# Add scheduler pallet in substrate

Tags: pallet, config

I am running into issues adding the scheduler pallet to my Substrate chain. Here are the steps I followed:

1. Clone the repo

```
git clone https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template
```

2. cd substrate-node-template
3. cargo build --release
4. Add scheduler-pallet
   Add this line in runtime cargo.toml

```
pallet-scheduler = { default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.23" }

'pallet-scheduler/std',
```

5. Check that the new dependencies resolve correctly by running the following command:

```
cargo check -p node-template-runtime
```

6. error show below

```rust
impl pallet_scheduler::Config for Runtime {}
      |      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait frame_system::pallet::Config is not implemented for Runtime
```

Comment: please share your code

Answer (score 1):

The error is saying you have not implemented the `frame_system::Config` for your runtime. So you are missing some code block like:

```rust
impl frame_system::Config for Runtime {
    type BaseCallFilter = Everything;
    type BlockWeights = RuntimeBlockWeights;
    type BlockLength = RuntimeBlockLength;
    type DbWeight = RocksDbWeight;
    type Origin = Origin;
    type Call = Call;
    type Index = Index;
    type BlockNumber = BlockNumber;
    type Hash = Hash;
    type Hashing = BlakeTwo256;
    type AccountId = AccountId;
    type Lookup = Indices;
    type Header = generic::Header<BlockNumber, BlakeTwo256>;
    type Event = Event;
    type BlockHashCount = BlockHashCount;
    type Version = Version;
    type PalletInfo = PalletInfo;
    type AccountData = pallet_balances::AccountData<Balance>;
    type OnNewAccount = ();
    type OnKilledAccount = ();
    type SystemWeightInfo = frame_system::weights::SubstrateWeight<Runtime>;
    type SS58Prefix = ConstU16<42>;
    type OnSetCode = ();
    type MaxConsumers = ConstU32<16>;
}
```

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L203

Also your `pallet_scheduler::Config` looks empty when it should be something like:

```rust
impl pallet_scheduler::Config for Runtime {
    type Event = Event;
    type Origin = Origin;
    type PalletsOrigin = OriginCaller;
    type Call = Call;
    type MaximumWeight = MaximumSchedulerWeight;
    type ScheduleOrigin = EnsureRoot<AccountId>;
    type MaxScheduledPerBlock = ConstU32<50>;
    type WeightInfo = pallet_scheduler::weights::SubstrateWeight<Runtime>;
    type OriginPrivilegeCmp = EqualPrivilegeOnly;
    type PreimageProvider = Preimage;
    type NoPreimagePostponement = NoPreimagePostponement;
}
```

End of the day, you have not followed all the correct steps to add a pallet to your runtime, and I suggest you look at the code inside the included Substrate node.

Comment: impl pallet_scheduler::Config for Runtime {
      |      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `frame_system::pallet::Config` is not implemented for `Runtime`

Comment: pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {
      |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `pallet_scheduler::Config`

Comment: This Error comes After doing above solution

Answer (score 0):

You have to add pallet_scheduler in runtime-benchmarks, try-runtime in cargo.toml and also in construct_runtime and benchmarks in runtime/lib.rs

Comment: i Am already set this

Comment: giving below error

Comment: pub struct UncheckedExtrinsic<Address, Call, Signature, Extra>
      |                                        ^^^^ required by this bound in `sp_runtime::generic::UncheckedExtrinsic`
      = note: this error originates in the macro `frame_support::construct_runtime` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)